# Troubleshooting high Document Metrics in MongoDB Cloud Manager

Tags: mongodb, troubleshooting

I am troubleshooting an incident where we receive a spike in document metrics during the incident according to MongoDB's cloud manager. Does anyone know what are some possible causes for this? Other indications of these causes?